# How can I delete a project shared into SVN repository?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I work under Ubuntu and use Eclipse+Subversive to commit code to my SVN repository.

I accidentally shared a project I don't want to be shared. I disconnected it, but obviously I can still see it (e.g. via websvn interface).

How can I delete this project (folder) from the repository itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "svn rm URL" command.

See "svn help rm" for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the repo-browser of your subversion client (that's what its called in tortoise) to access the subversion structure directly and do your maintenance there.